# <Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'prototype')> error on running build version of a vite+vue3 chrome extension

Tags: jquery, vuejs3, vite, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Everything is right when I run the project in `dev` mode. But after build, when I run dist folder by `live-server`, this error appears: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'prototype')')`.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.25",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@crxjs/vite-plugin": "^1.0.14",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
}
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'
import manifest from './manifest.json' assert { type: 'json' }
import $ from 'jquery'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), crx({ manifest })],
  define: {
    $: JSON.stringify($),
    jQuery: JSON.stringify($)
  }
})
```

Comment: Debug it in devtools to find where exactly the error occurs. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. See also the [background console](/a/10258029).